# ETL data over one column but put partition different column. How can I do it faster?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I ve a mapping to etl one big table has about 3 billion records.

That table has partition on `RECORDDATE` column and I load just yesterday data to stage table and after stage table loads finished I use `exchange_partition` to load data to main table.

This works fine. But we need to put partition to different column ( `OTHERDATECOLUMN`) But still I want to get data on `RECORDDATE` column. So I cant use `exchange_partition` and I need to delete records first then insert directly to main table. This is slow.

How can I solve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understood everything you said, but: if it is an Oracle table and it is partitioned, then you don't have to DELETE data related to that partition (which is slow), but **truncate** the partition (which is fast). Please, test it first! so that you wouldn't lose data.

Comment: I'd need more info: is the date range between RECORDDATE and OTHERDATECOLUMN different? Are you processing a set of data for one day by RECORDDATE that has different values for OTHERDATECOLUMN?

Comment: @Littlefoot i dont want to truncate partition because I get records by looking different column and partition on different column.

Comment: @Maciejg yes it is different set of data by two columns

Comment: is it possible to exchange partition using third table? Like you copy the stg table data into a third temp table - which is partitioned like main table and then exchange partition with main table and this third table. I know this is not a good solution considering resource, but it can save your delete time from main table.

Comment: @KoushikRoy thanks , but third table data does not have all data because I get data looking another column

Comment: One last question: once you fetch data for a given day of RECORDDATE, does it hold all data for the OTHERDATECOLUMN you need? I mean if e.g. we get rows where RECORDDATE = 2020.05.01 and in OTHERDATECOLUMN we get 2020.05.01, 2020.05.02, 2020.05.03 - do you delete ALL data from target where OTHERDATECOLUMN in ("2020.05.01", "2020.05.02", "2020.05.03")?

Comment: @Maciejg , One last question: once you fetch data for a given day of RECORDDATE, does it hold all data for the OTHERDATECOLUMN you need? 
**answer** unfortunatelly no

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing all the comments I don't see any quick&clever solution. Either use the simple delete - although it takes long, or...

Try to load your data in sequence, in few steps - as follows:

- Check how many different `OTHERDATECOLUMN` dates you have for your `RECORDDATE` dataset
- Now a loop: for each date in `OTHERDATECOLUMN`:

  - Get one date data and load to `TEMP` table
  - Add all data from `TARGET` table - except what needs to be replaced with the new data(*) (see the sample query below for clarifications)
  - Use `Exchange partition` (just as originally) to get the data from TEMP_TABLE to TARGET_TABLE

(*) The query to load from TARGET_TABLE the data that is not in TEMP_TABLE

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
SELECT * FROM TARGET_TABLE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE TARGET_TABLE.ID = TEMP_TABLE.ID)
```

I hope I'm making myself clear :)